# How to allow for both portrait ipad orientation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

I have developed an iPad application with portrait orientation, but my application was rejected stating the following reason:

> app does not comply with the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines, as
>   required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, app only supported the bottom-up variant of the portrait
>   orientation, but not the top-up variant.
>
> While supporting both variants of both orientations, each with unique
>   launch images, provides the best user experience and is recommended,
>   we understand there are certain applications that must run in the
>   portrait orientation only. In this case, it would be appropriate to
>   support both variants of that orientation in your application, e.g.,
>   Home button up and down."

I have some changes in the code but still only my status bar is rotating in both portrait orientation and does not use the whole uiview.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
**See the screenshot..you can see the portrait mode being the darker one.**
that is funny.. have you tested your app...how did you use your iPad ..bottom side up?? from your question it is confirmed that you have to use your app with iPad upside down...? is it true.(didn't you find it uncomfortable.)?

Well if that is the case..open your project..click on project name(blue Xcode icon) in the project navigator and in the middle now there will be option to support device orientations..just make sure the darkened one is only portrait..the first one in the four..

Comment: I am not getting any option can you help me out with this where actually the options comes.

Comment: but i want to rotate my view with both orienation i.e. portrait with home button up and down, How can i achieve this is there any coding needed for this.

Comment: set both portrait and upside down to be darker in the above image

Comment: I have implemented this but only the launch images appears to be in both portrait orientation and not the others screens how can i do this  please provide me with some solution and thanks for your help.

Comment: in your every view controller class there will be a method should rotate to orientation.. find it and return both portrait and upside down.

Comment: NO i cannot discuss on chat can you please suggest me some solution on comments. Thanks